# how to read a json file containing url and save the url

Tags: php, json

I have a json file. The json file contains the path of some images. I want to read the url path and save the image in my computer. I was able to read the json file but can't get the image_path object in the json. My json file is of the format:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 262
                    [product_name] => VD0289 CUT OUT BACK DRESS
                    [product_inventory] => 2
                    [product_price] => B
                    [label_name] => 15
                    [product_status] => A
                    [images] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [image_id] => 935
                                    [image_path] => http://gird.com/images/thumbnails/0/400/500/VD0289_VD0289.jpg
                                    [image_thumbnail] => http://gird.com/images/thumbnails/0/60/60/VD0289_VD0289.jpg
                                    [image_detailed] => http://gird.com/images/detailed/0/VD0289_VD0289.jpg
                                    [image_type] => M
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [image_id] => 938
                                    [image_path] => http://gird.com/images/thumbnails/0/400/500/VD0289_VD0289_(4).jpg
                                    [image_thumbnail] => http://gird.com/images/thumbnails/0/60/60/VD0289_VD0289_(4).jpg
                                    [image_detailed] => http://gird.com/images/detailed/0/VD0289_VD0289_(4).jpg
                                    [image_type] => A
                                )



                        )

                    [options] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 263
                    [product_name] => Chic Chanel Inspired Dress - Blue
                    [product_inventory] => 1
                    [product_price] => O
                    [label_name] => 9
                    [product_status] => A
                    [images] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [image_id] => 939
                                    [image_path] => http://gird.com/images/thumbnails/0/400/500/100678-Blue-1.jpg
                                    [image_thumbnail] => http://gird.com/images/thumbnails/0/60/60/100678-Blue-1.jpg
                                    [image_detailed] => http://gird.com/images/detailed/0/100678-Blue-1.jpg
                                    [image_type] => M
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [image_id] => 942
                                    [image_path] => http://gird.com/images/thumbnails/0/400/500/100678-Blue-4.jpg
                                    [image_thumbnail] => http://gird.com/images/thumbnails/0/60/60/100678-Blue-4.jpg
                                    [image_detailed] => http://gird.com/images/detailed/0/100678-Blue-4.jpg
                                    [image_type] => A
                                )

                         ..............................
```

How can I get all the image path and image_detailed from this file?? My php code is:The code is to only get the first image path.

```
<?php

$file="dw.json";

$json=  json_decode(file_get_contents($file),true);
print_r ($json[0]["product"]["images"][0]["image_path"]);
//print_r($json);
?>
```

Comment: So the code to get the first one works. Why not try using a loop?

Comment: It works thats the thing I don't know how to put it in a loop because the images does not have a fixed number of array inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
foreach($json as $key => $products) {
$product = $products['product'];
    foreach($product['images'] as $key => $image) {
        $product_images[$product['product_name']][] = $image['image_path'];
    }
}

print_r($product_images);
```

Comment: didn't work. I get the error undefined index images and invalid argument supplied for foreach for the second foreach loop.

Comment: Weird, I guess because it has the counter and each has the `product` key, I have to dig the extra step. Tested the above with your array and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop, like this:

```
foreach ($json[0]["product"]["images"] as $key)
    echo $key['image_path'];
```

Comment: it does not work for the whole file as the $json[0] only works for the first array so I think we shud put the $json in an array too??